# Update database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api

I am struggling to get .put or .patch to work. when using postman I get the call back returned but the values are not updated in my database on robo 3t. I have tried fixing the deprecation warning and  using updateOne, updateMany.

This will fix the deprecation warning but will not update the database. Here is the code before i fix the deprecation. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
////////////////////Request Targeting A Specific Article///////////////////////


app.route("/articles/:articleTitle")

.get(function(req, res){

Article.findOne({title: req.params.articleTitle}, function(err, foundArticle){
 if (foundArticle) {
   res.send(foundArticle);
 } else {
   res.send("No articles with that title.");
 }
});
})

/////////PUT PROBLEM MUST BE FIXED /////////////

.put(function(req, res){
Article.update(
 {title: req.params.articleTitle},
 {title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content},
 {overwrite: true},
 function(err){
   if(!err){
     res.send("succesfully updated");
   }
 }
);
})

///////PATCH PROBLEM MUST BE FIXED ///////////

.patch(function(req, res){

Article.update(
 {title: req.params.articleTitle},
 {$set: req.body},
 function(err){
   if(!err){
     res.send("Successfully updated article.");
   } else{
     res.send(err);
   }
 }
);
});
```

Comment: Did you try the same query on Robo 3T? Usually I when I have troubles I try the query on the editor, and if it works I then proceed to troubleshoot the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 

app.route("/articles/:articleTitle")
  .get((req, res) => {
    Article.findOne({ title: req.params.articleTitle }, (err, result) => {
      if (result) {
        res.send(result);
      } else {
        res.send("err");
      }
    });
  })
  .put((req, res) => {
    Article.replaceOne(
      { title: req.params.articleTitle },
      { title: req.body.title, content: req.body.content },
      { overwrite: true },
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          res.send("There is some error");
        } else {
          res.send("Updated successfully");
        }
      }
    );
  })

  .patch((req, res) => {
    Article.updateOne(
      { title: req.params.articleTitle },
      { $set: req.body },
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          res.send("There is some error");
        } else {
          res.send("Updated successfully");
        }
      }
    );
  });
```

```html
Try this!! this will work fine.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).